# pasar un id y un nombre de php a javascript y devolverlo

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

en php cojo un id y un nombre de mi base de datos en mysql y muestro cada nombre en un checkbox.
El problema es que necesito marcar varios y darle a un botón para eliminarlos y para ello muestro en javascript un mensaje confirm por seguridad. Al mensaje confirm le paso los nombres pero también necesito pasarle el id ya que al volver a php necesito el id para realziar otra consulta y eliminar los que haya marcado.
En el php:

```
echo "<form name=form method=POST action=principal.php?orden=desasignar>";
                    //Recorro la matriz para sacar el valor de todos que es el nombre
                    for($i=1;$i<=count($resultsetAsignado);$i++){
                        echo "<td><input type=checkbox name='clientes' value='".$resultsetAsignado[$i][1]."' id='idDelCliente'>".$resultsetAsignado[$i][1]."</td>";
                        //mandamos los id_de los clientes
                        echo "<input type=hidden name='id' value=".$resultsetAsignado[$i][0]." >";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                echo "</table>";
                //boton
                echo "<input type=button name=boton value='Desasignar' onClick='confirmacion();'>";
                echo "</form>";
```

En javascript

```
    function confirmacion(){
       //Realizo el confirm y cojo los nombres y los muestro en el confirm
      //y despues lo mando con submit
      document.form.submit();   
    }
```

En el 0 guardo el id y en el 1 el nombre.

Alguna idea? Si no se entiende algo decidme

Comment: Sugerencia (no respuesta): Si vas a trabajar con una lista de `checkbox` e `input`, que así parece al ver que recorres en el ciclo a `$resultsetAsignado`, recuerda agregar a cada `name` de los controles (tanto check como hidden) los corchetes, para indicar a php que son más de 1 valor los que vas a mandar. `<input type="checkbox" name="clientes[]" value="`...

Comment: Esto es una duda: No entiendo bien qué quieres decir cuando dices _Al mensaje confirm le paso los nombres pero también necesito pasarle el id_ : ¿en qué parte envías al "mensaje confirm" el nombre? ¿en qué parte de tu código aquí expuesto haces eso? ¿Te refieres a enviar el formulario a procesar por php?

Comment: Recomiento que mires Ajax de JQuery, con esta función podrás realizar lo que necesitas, de todos modos no entiendo muy bien lo que necesitas realizar, sospecho que no es necesario que le des muchas vueltas a las variables.

Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

los corchetes ya los puse pero me daba error en javascript al coger los datos y por eso los quite.
El mensaje lo mando pero no lo he puesto, porque eso no me daba problemas pero lo que hago es coger todos los marcados y mostrarlos y al aceptar hago el submit y si cancela no. El problema es coger el id para una vez marcados y mostrados los nombres en el confirm poder mandar los id al php para realizar la consulta de borado de los marcados.
Intentare con ayax pero no tengo mucha idea.